# How to connect through SOAP if i dont have any WSDL file or URL

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, wsdl

Rate Quote
Rate quote request must be sent to the following URL:SomeIPaddress/cgibin/
map/RATEQUOTE
Here is a sample schema of the Rate Quote Request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
- <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
- <soap12:Body>
- <request>
- <Details>
- <DetailItem>
<Weight>decimal</Weight>
<Class>decimal</Class>
</DetailItem>
</Details>
- <Accessorials>
- <AccessorialItem>
<Code>char</Code>
</AccessorialItem>
</Accessorials>
<BillingTerms>Char</BillingTerms>
<OriginCity>Char</OriginCity>
<OriginState>Char</OriginState>
<OriginZipcode>Char</OriginZipcode>
<DestinationCity>Char</DestinationCity>
<DestinationState>Char</DestinationState>
<DestinationZipcode>Char</DestinationZipcode>
<PalletCount>decimal</PalletCount>
<Customer>Char</Customer
```

I am using this coding for this but its not working showing errror previously i have used this method for many API's but i uesd to have .wsdl file:

```
    <? $client = new SoapClient('http://208.51.75.23:6082/cgi-bin/map/RATEQUOTE',array( 'trace' => 1,'exceptions' => 0 ));

$params = array("Details" => array("DetailItem" =>array("Weight" =>"3","Class" =>"55")),
            "Accessorials" => array("AccessorialItem"=>array("Code" =>"LIFTG")),
            "BillingTerms" => "FEEP", //Billing Terms:Prepaid Collect
            "OriginCity" => "Henrico",
            "OriginState" => "VA",
            "OriginZipcode" => "23229",
            "DestinationCity" => "LOS ANGELES",
            "DestinationState" => "CA",
            "DestinationZipcode" => "90001",
            "PalletCount" => "1",
            "Customer" => "abc",
);
    $return = $client->CreateResult->$params;
    print_r($return);die;



?>
```

Comment: So you got url or not?

Comment: i got a URL but its not wsdl

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you need an IP Address or URL to connect to, or it needs to be contained in the WSDL file. Otherwise, you can never know where to connect to...

Comment: i have an IP address can i use intead of WSDL

Comment: @user2750385: An ip address === a url! For example this site is actually [198.252.206.16](http://www.whoisstuff.net/ip-lookup.php?domain=198.252.206.16)

Comment: i got a URL but its not WSDl

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem IP !== URL ;p But IP == domain, so with path it'll be enough.

Comment: @ElonThan: Fair enough, but OP mentions path in his question, so `8.8.8.8/cgibin/ map/RATEQUOTE` is his URL, where 8.8.8.8 should be replaced. Through use of [the `__soapCall` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php), he's able to do whatever needs doing

Comment: can't get it to work using this now: $client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => $URL,
    'uri'      => "http://208.51.75.23:6082/cgi-bin/map/",
    'trace'    => 1,
    ));

Comment: This is the Detail they sent me ""Rate Quote
Rate quote request must be sent to the following URL: http://208.51.75.23:6082/cgibin/
map/RATEQUOTE
Here is a sample schema of the Rate Quote Request.""
I have only this URL nothing else and xml schema which i have entered on the top